# Calling ASP.NET ASMX Web Service from jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, soap, asmx

I am trying to call an ASMX from jQuery using JSON and get a SOAP error response.

What am I doing wrong?!

This is my jQuery call:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Services/TeamPerson.asmx',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {'active':false, 'team_id':team_id, 'player_id':player_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(xhr, msg) { alert(msg + '\n' + xhr.responseText); }
          });
```

This is my web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [ToolboxItem(false)]
  [ScriptService]
  public class TeamPerson : WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void SetPlayerStatus(bool active, ulong team_id, ulong player_id)
    {
      // blah blah
    }
  }
```

I get a nasty SOAP error back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code>
    <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code>
    <soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">
     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; 
     System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.   
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)    
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()   
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()    
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()    
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()    
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()    
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()    
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)    
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I can hit `/Services/TeamPerson.asmx` via my browser and the web method works fine. I also have the following defined in web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
   <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
   <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="TinyMCEHandler.aspx" type="Moxiecode.TinyMCE.Web.HttpHandler,Moxiecode.TinyMCE" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
   <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not defining which method to call on the service. Try changing your JQuery line `url: '/Services/TeamPerson.asmx',` to `url: '/Services/TeamPerson.asmx/SetPlayerStatus',`

Comment: That made a big difference, thanks! Now I'm just getting this error: {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: active.","StackTrace":"   at ... 

Am I passing the data {} params in wrong?

Comment: Ah! i didn't realize data needed to be a quoted string param. This worked:
data: "{'active':'false', 'team_id':" + team_id + ", 'player_id':" + player_id + "}",

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it's the web method missing in the URL, as well as the parameters.

```
var teamID = 123;
var playerID = 456;
var active = true;
var webMethod = 'http://foo.net/TeamPerson.asmx/SetPlayerStatus'
var parameters = "{'active':'" + active + 
                 "','team_id':'" + teamID + 
                 "','player_id':'" + playerID + "'}"

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {    
               alert('all good');
        },
        error: function(e){
               alert('err');
        }
});
```

Comment: Its old, i know, but.... why you do not use  JSON.stringify(parameters) in the "data" parameter?